# Multiple image change on mouse hover over an image

Tags: java, image, swing, hover, mouse

I want to get the solution for a Java program. I want to change the image in a rectangular box as soon as the mouse cursor hovers over the box. The images in the box has to keep on changing (at least 5 different images) till the mouse is on the images and stop changing as the cursor goes out of the box.I want to set the images using only the `g.drawImage()`, where **g** is a Graphics2D object.

Please help me figure out this problem as i am stuck.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556) though for this it might be simpler to generate different sized images in code at run-time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code may help you some!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class answer {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public answer(){
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new rectangle());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new answer();
    }

    public class rectangle extends JPanel{
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        Image img;
        Timer timer;
        int count=0;
        public rectangle() {

            setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.black));
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
            timer=new Timer(800, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    loadPic(count%5);
                    count++;
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }
            });

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    count=0;
                    timer.start();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    timer.stop();
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 120, 100,this);
        }

        public void loadPic(int number){

            String address="";

            switch(number){
            case 0: address="img1.jpg";
            break;
            case 1: address="img2.jpg";
            break;
            case 2: address="img3.jpg";
            break;
            case 3: address="img4.jpg";
            break;
            default: address="img5.jpg";
            break;
            }

            try  
            {  
                img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(address));

            }  
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("error in loading image");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *"This code may help you some!"*  The code extends `JFrame` without needing to do that (just keep an instance of a standard `JFrame`).  It fails to start the GUI on the EDT.  It packs after setting the frame visible, possibly altering the viewable size.  It tries to load each image whenever there is a change, rather than simply keeping a reference to all 5 images. ..  Or to put that another way, it is not code that other code should be based on.

Comment: Guidance is well invested in changes to working practices and [edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21851519/edit) to answers.  ;)

Comment: BTW - One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Answer (score 2):

Start with [How to Write a Mouse-Motion Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html).  You will need to determine when the mouse enters your prescribed area, you can use a `java.awt.Rectangle` to help with this as it has a `contains(Point)` method.

Then, take a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), which you can use to trigger the changes in the picture.

Basically, as the mouse moves into your `Rectangle`, you would start the Swing `Timer`, which would trigger an action event, where by you would update which picture was to be displayed and call `repaint`.  When the mouse moves out side of the `Rectangle` you would simply stop the timer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ImageIcon` array add set all path in `ImageIcon` when mouse enter on label, the image changes after 1 second.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class myImage extends JFrame implements  MouseMotionListener
{
    ImageIcon[] m=new ImageIcon[2]; 
    JLabel l;
    int i,l1;
    public myImage()
    {
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(1000,1000);
        setVisible(true);
        m[0]=new ImageIcon("m.jpg");
        m[1]=new ImageIcon("m1.jpg");
        l=new JLabel();
        l.setBounds(400,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
        add(l);
        l.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        if(i<2)
        {
            l.setIcon(m[i]);
            i++;
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(Exception e1)
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i=0;
        }
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        System.out.print("Mouse bye");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        myImage i1=new myImage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!

Comment: You're blocking the EDT, using a null layout when the OP explicitly said they wanted to drawImage